# How to use Silverstripe 3 beta UploadField

Tags: silverstripe

I am trying to use a UploadField on frontend for user to upload their company logo.

There isn't much documentation on UploadField yet. And I have tried it but no luck so far.

Can anyone guide me on how to use it?

Comment: there doesn't seem to be much documentation covering uploadfield yet, so for the time being we're left alone with the code itself (there's some comments in the uploadfield class). guess this will soon get better when 3.0 stable is released.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little old, but if anyone else stumbles upon this like I did.

UploadField does work frontend. I haven't been able to save into a many_many relationship using the saveInto function. But the biggest thing I missed was the DataObject/Page needs to exist first, as in it needs to be saved before you can attach a related object like an image.

```
static $has_one = array(
    "Photo" => "Image"
);

$fields = new FieldList(
    new UploadField( 'Photo', 'Upload' )
);

function saveForm( $data, $form ) {
    $object = new DataObject();
    // for a new object write before saveinto
    $object->write();
    $form->saveInto($object);
    $object->write();
    Director::redirectBack();
}
```

using ss 3.0.1

Alternatively rather than using the saveinto function you can manually loop over the parameters and attach them on the object yourself for many_many images.

Answer (score 0):

The upload field checks for permissions via the can*() methods in the object.

In order to allow front end editing - you may have to overload File::canEdit (or Image::canEdit) in your custom object to handle this.

Comment: Hi Tim, from the SS documentation it says that the upload field is able to 'Saving into relations'. I have a has-one relation in my dataobject, for eg, static $has_one = array('ProfilePhoto' => 'Image');. When I create the form with the upload field with the name 'ProfilePhoto', it is able to upload successfully, but it doesn't seems to be able to save into relations. I created the upload field as the code below: new UploadField('ProfilePhoto', 'Profile Photo'); Do you have any idea?

Comment: Hi Joe, just letting you know - I am stuck with the same problem in the moment and am trying to find a nice solution. Will let you know as soon as I find something! Cheers

Comment: The UploadField is, as far as I know, not yet ready for frontend, so its highly likely that this is a bug in the UploadField.
It is planed to make it work in frontend, but so far no one had time to do it I think, the list of todo's and bugs to fix is pretty long :S